# I have my Ethereum account address and password. That's all I need to access it, right?

Tags: ethereum

I created my new Ethereum address with "geth account new", set a password and transferred some ethers there. Now that I have this account # (hash) and password, I can always access this account, right?

Answer (score 3):

**WRONG.** You must have the **keystore** for the account as well. If you bought in the presale, this is the .json file that was provided to you. If you created accounts later, a private key for each account is created and stashed your root ethereum directory. On Linux, that directory is /home/yourusername/.ethereum/keystore and the key filename is in the form: "UTC--2015-11-16T11-52-22.592017989Z--". Back up this directory and its private key files regularly to ensure access to all your accounts.

So to sum up you need 2 things:

1. Your private key file or "wallet" (.json or "UTC--" file, contains account number)
2. Your password